# Why is the title "Honey, I Shrunk the Kids"?

Tags: title, honey-i-shrunk-the-kids

The kids get themselves shrunk by a machine when a baseball hits the button on the machine.  Wayne Szalinski didn't actually control the machine at all when the kids were shrunk.

Why is the title "Honey, I Shrunk the Kids"?  It implies that Wayne Szalinski, intentionally or accidentally, had a hand in the kids getting shrunk even though he didn't.

Comment: Well, it was his machine that actually shrunk the kids...

Comment: so how title justified the plot here? there is no involvement of him.

Comment: Because the kids were shrunk by his machine while the mother was away...hence "Honey, I shrunk the kids."  He was quite involved in the entire movie.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Because it's more of a catchy title

*It's not meant literally*..as you have pointed out but the title for movies such as this is part of the overall marketing package.

In fact, the original title was different.

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey,_I_Shrunk_the_Kids#Production)

> The film was written as ***Teeny Weenies***...[snip]..
>
> As *Teeny Weenies* seemed to appeal more to a child demographic, the name was changed to *Grounded* to appeal to a more mature audience. That name was later rejected in favour of *The Big Backyard*.
>
> *Honey, I Shrunk the Kids*, **a line of dialogue from the film**, ultimately became its title.

Comment: Speaking as a non-American yet English as a first language [UK] - The phrase "Honey, I [something]" is a throw-back to *"all"* US sitcoms from the 50's onwards, so the title makes it 'chummy' & 'endearing'... with a twist. ...maybe a less-scary version of "Honey, I'm home" referenced in The Shining.